# auto-configure ClientRegistrationRepository in a non-web Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing a batch using Spring Boot 2.7.1 and `spring-boot-starter-batch` . The batch needs 2 different `WebClient` to call 2 different APIs with different authentication systems, that I configure through standard Spring Boot properties (spring.security.oauth2.client etc).

It works well, but I realized the batch was listening on port 8080 when running, because I have imported `spring-boot-starter-web` , which enables the auto-configuration of my `WebClient` , by injecting a `ClientRegistrationRepository` . It's not a major issue, but it prevents me from launching the batch twice in parallel for instance, because the port is already used... so I would like to disable the web server part.

The problem is that when I disable the web server,  either through properties, code or dependencies (by removing `spring-boot-starter-web`), then the batch doesn't start anymore, because `ClientRegistrationRepository` is not loaded anymore, because I require

```
a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found
```

This is because, there's a conditional on Spring's `OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration` :

```
@AutoConfiguration(before = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ EnableWebSecurity.class, ClientRegistration.class })
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
@Import({ OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class, OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class })
public class OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Because the application is not of type `SERVLET`, but `NONE`, this doesn't get enabled.

I've tried to "force load" it :

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration.class)
```

but it doesn't work.

Looking into the source code, I see that `OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration` is actually loading 2 config classes, but they are not public, so I can't import them directly :

```
@Import({ OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class, OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class })
```

there must be a trick to achieve that.. but what is it ?

Comment: You have disable the web server using properties means you have used `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` and your batch application wont start if you add this property?

Comment: yes, it doesn't start, because the batch still needs to have webClient properly configured (to call remote APIs), but ClientRegistrationRepository is missing and batch fails to start

Comment: Including the `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` doesnt exclude the web libraries, can you share the logs by setting the log level to trace.

Comment: I have updated the question, showing why OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration doesn't get enabled when the application type is NONE : the binary is here, but it's explicitly not enabled because of that.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot, you can customize the port of your webapplication by setting the property `server.port=8095` in your `application.properties` or any customized env properties file ie `application-dev.properties`, `application-prod.properties` and so on.

Using these property, your webapplication will listen on the port of your choice and will not conflict anymore with other stuff. And if you need multiple instances running in parallel, run them with a range of ports could be great (@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884100/390462. You can add listeners too (@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876661/390462). Or at least multiple instances of your batch application with differents `server.port` values.

If you want to disable the webserver, the best bet is to use the property : `spring.main.web-application-type=none`.

I've just found something interesting using `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` in your service layer (@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60173451/390462

Comment: but instead of changing the server.port, the more logical thing would be to not run the server at all, which is what I am trying to do

Comment: Using `spring.main.web-application-type=none` could do the job then.

Comment: Just see your edit now, did you try to create a custom annotation without these conditionnal statment and call your class with it ?

Comment: since the actual Configuration classes are not public, I would also need to copy paste them... I can try that, but I may end up copy pasting more things, and it definitely looks like a hack, not very "SpringBoot-ish"

Comment: The web security layer is required for oauth anyway, so servlet dependencies are mandatory. It seems to be a wrong way to go with custom annotation. If I were you, I will go for a working way now (the first way I suggested), and seek a better solution in the background.

Comment: that's what I am doing ;-) I am just surprised to be the first one having the issue ;-)

Comment: I've just found something interesting in service layer with oauth. Answer updated with it.

Comment: Okay, maybe you are the first one to talk about it here, maybe not ;) It didn't use OAuth to run any batch applications without the web layer, so it is new here ;) But I have worked on many projects where batch were done with some schedulers impl with or without cron task to do them with hundreds of To of datas. Hope you'll find a way.

Answer (score 1):

I have manual approach, think it would be helpful, because it is quite simple:

make the config:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak") //use your oauth2 properties
 @Getter
 @Setter
 public class Oauth2KeycloakProperties {
     private String clientSecret;
     ...
 }
```

Create ClientRegistrationRepository manually:

```
@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(Oauth2KeycloakProperties properties) {
    ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId(properties.getRegistrationId())
            .authorizationGrantType(properties.getAuthorizationGrantType())
            .clientId(properties.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(properties.getClientSecret())                 
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .scope(properties.getScope())
            .tokenUri(properties.getTokenUri())
            .clientName(properties.getClientName())
            .build();
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(List.of(registration));
    }
```

Create ClientService bean:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
```

Also you may need jackson-databind dependency, because there is a bug in message converter and the token's expires_in field is deserializes as a Double, instead of an Integer and spring will request a new token on every request

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```